# Expanding the recently closed list

Tags: support

How do you get to a list of recently closed questions longer than what you can get by going to tools/close and expanding the recently closed list there?  There is fixed number which show and no way, AFAIS, to show more.

Why do I care? For housekeeping.  10K users cannot vote to delete questions until two days after closing.  We get so many trash questions on MO that the two day old closed questions are pushed off the Recently Closed page.

Comment: Bill, you can bookmark the following link: http://mathoverflow.net/search?tab=newest&q=closed%3ayes

Comment: Yes, that looks like the best way.  Thanks, Kaveh.

Comment: @BillJohnson (off-topic) if you find yourself about to delete a closed question which is by that pseudonymous ultrapower person, could you please let me know, e.g. by email? (Feel free to email me if you want more information on my motives.)

Comment: Sure, Yemon; will do.

Answer (score 4):

Search `closed:1` and sort by newest. See the "advanced search tips" sidebar on the search page for more such search operators.

10k users can see recently closed posts and posts with pending close votes on [`/tools?tab=close`](https://mathoverflow.net/tools?tab=close)

Also, note that *most* bad, closed posts get [autodeleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/178438)

Comment: Thanks, but why is it so complicated? Why is there no link to the search page?  It is not very intuitive to click on a blank box to get to it.  Finally, the language that the Advanced Search Tips are written in is for me more difficult than Latin and only slightly easier than Greek.

Comment: @BillJohnson see edit. Also, this is something you rarely need to do.

Comment: On the contrary, I need to do it almost every day.

Comment: @BillJohnson Care to specify why? (do so in your question itself, makes it more prominent)

Comment: Manishearth: I also do it every day, I guess, for the same reason I regularly take out trash in my house,  etc.

Comment: @Misha Hmm? But these are recently _closed_ questions (or are you looking for questions that may need improvement and reopening?). Not questions yet-to-be-closed.

Comment: @Manishearth: These are potentially questions to be deleted (because of extremely low quality). Leaving these on the site pollutes MO.

Comment: @MarkSapir Oh, downvoted closed questions get autodeleted in 9 days now. :)

Comment: @Mark See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/178438

Comment: @Misha see above comment, closed,downvoted, unanswered posts get autodeleted.

Comment: Getting autodeletion is an improvement.

Comment: @Manishearth: Good to know, such autodeletion is a new thing comparing to the old MO.

Comment: "No accepted answer" as grounds for autodelete? This is prone to abuse...

Comment: @darijgrinberg Meh, the ones who post closed questions won't know the intricacies. And remember that _most_ really-bad-should-be-deleted posts don't get answers at all. You can still go through the list of closes, just that you don't need to do it every day.